# Pluriel de « code postal »

Tags: pluriel

Quel est le pluriel de « un code postal » ?

Doit-on dire « des codes postaux » ou « des codes postal » ?

Comment: On dit "des codes postaux".

Comment: @Lamine mais on dit des selles à cheval, non?

Comment: Ce n'est pas la même chose. Dans "code postal", le mot "postal" est un adjectif qui se rapporte à "code", il doit donc être accordé. "A cheval" est un complément circonstanciel, il ne s'accorde pas.

Comment: En fait, je ne suis pas sûr que "à cheval" soit un complément circonstanciel, c'est peut être un complément de nom. Mais dans tous les cas ça ne s'accorde pas.

Comment: @Lamine, vous devriez poster votre réponse de sorte qu'elle soit acceptée.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On dit "des codes postaux".

Dans "code postal", le mot "postal" est un adjectif qui se rapporte à "code", il doit donc être accordé. "A cheval" est un complément (circonstanciel ou de nom, je ne sais plus). Il ne s'accorde pas.

Comment: De même, on dit _une corbeille à fruits_ même s'il n'y a qu'une corbeille et même si elle ne contient qu'une banane.